# How to test dependency injection Jest with inject Token Angular

Tags: angular, jestjs

I have the following test

```
describe('HttpClientService', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      declarations: [],
      providers: [
        HttpClientService,
        { provide: HTTP_CLIENT, useClass: MockHttpClient }
      ]
    }).compileComponents()
    service = TestBed.inject(HttpClientService)
  })

  test('Should create service', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy()
  })

  test('Should request post with correct url', fakeAsync(() => {
    service['_http'].post = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(of())
    const url = faker.internet.url()
    const body = faker.random.objectElement()
    service.post(url, body)
    tick()
    expect(service['_http'].post).toHaveBeenCalledWith(url, body)
  }))
})
```

Notice that I'm taking a direct reference from the dependency  `service['_http'].post = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(of())`
I want to know if I can test dependency injection in a healthier way with testbed.inject(InterfaceInjector), or this is is best practices?

Comment: It would be better to get the `MockHttpClient` instance from the injector, so your tests aren't coupled to a private property of the component, but more broadly why not use the approach in the docs: https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests.

Comment: it doesn't make sense since the dependency comes from an interface

Comment: I need somehow jest understood that the interface I am injecting uses a mock class

Comment: service = TestBed.inject(MyInterface) obviously it won't work so I didn't inject it into it, and my question was clear: how can I inject a @inject() dependency using an interface?

Comment: Your question may be clear to you, but it certainly isn't to me. What _are_ `InterfaceInjector`, `MyInterface`? _"the dependency comes from an interface"_ - what? Based on `{ provide: HTTP_CLIENT, useClass: MockHttpClient }` (we have to guess, you didn't give a [mre]) `HTTP_CLIENT` is a _token_ and `MockHttpClient` is a _class_ - both have _values_, neither is just an interface. You might find this all easier if you `useValue`, then you already have the value and don't need to ask the injector for it, or use the built-in testing tools in the link I shared.